# How to setup VPC to VPC connection without VPN?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-vpc

I am looking to find a way to communicate between 2 VPCs in AWS without the use of VPN connections to and from a certain company (outside AWS) - so that the traffic does not pass through the company's gateway. Or, simply said, access an EC2 instance in a VPC from another VPC (both in AWS) without leaving the Amazon Network (not going out on the internet, not even encrypted).

Basically what I want to do is to have a VPC acting as a "proxy" (let's call it PROX) and one acting as a "target" (called TARG). Now I want to connect a company through VPC to the PROX and inside the PROX route the requests to the TARG. Is this achievable? I would go for a traditional public-private single VPC, but I was asked to look into the previously described "architecture".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use two Linux machines as VPN GW, each in each VPC.
Configure IPsec VPN between them.

That's all you need

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  You have to use a VPN connection between the two VPCs.  You can directly connect them though relatively easily using the pair of IPSec gateways though.  This is the recommended method of cross-connecting VPC's across regions.